# R Shiny - ERROR: object 'template_dfa' not found

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to create a shiny dashboard. However, even when I create a blank dashboard, I get an error message. This is my dashboard code:

```
library(shiny)
library (shinydashboard)


ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(), 
    dashboardSidebar(), 
    dashboardBody()
)
    
server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I click on "Run App" the following error message appears:

```
Attaching package: ‘shinydashboard’

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    box

This version of bslib is designed to work with rmarkdown version 2.7 or higher.


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5024
Warning: Error in htmlTemplate: object 'template_dfa' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

The dashboard opens, but only the error message "ERROR: objeckt template_dfa not found" is displayed in the dashboard.

What can I do to solve this problem? Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Your code runs without error and a (blank) app is displayed.  Have you tried restarting RStudio?

Comment: Yes, I have already restarted R Studio. Unfortunately, I still get the following error message: "ERROR: objeckt template_dfa not found".

Comment: `template_dfa` is part of `htmltools`, in C code (https://github.com/rstudio/htmltools/blob/master/src/template.c#L26). I suggest you re-install `htmltools`, restart R and RStudio, then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about what causes the problem but manage to repair it locally reinstalling certain packages' versions.

(I use R 3.3.3 and have Rtools 35 installed)

```r
## restart session through ctrl F10 between each install

packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/rlang/rlang_0.4.10.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fastmap/fastmap_1.1.0.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")

packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/htmltools/htmltools_0.5.3.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Hope it fixes yours as well.